# Weird characters printed during json key-value printing

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

I have made a python program to get the movie/tv show information using the OMDb API http://www.omdbapi.com/

I am getting an error while printing the running years of the tv show. Here's a part of the code where this is happening:

```
keys = ['Title', 'Year', 'imdbRating', 'Director', 'Actors', 'Genre', 'totalSeasons']

def jsonContent(self):
        payload = {'t':self.title}
        movie = requests.get(self.url, params = payload)
        return movie.json()

def getInfo(self):
        data = self.jsonContent()
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key in keys:
                print key.encode('utf-8') + ' : ' + value.encode('utf-8')
```

For example if I search for *How I Met Your Mother*, it prints out like this:

```
totalSeasons : 9
Title : How I Met Your Mother
imdbRating : 8.4
Director : N/A
Actors : Josh Radnor, Jason Segel, Cobie Smulders, Neil Patrick Harris
Year : 2005ΓÇô2014     #problem here
Genre : Comedy, Romance
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems to be an encoding problem. Perhaps the fix you put into your code is not necessary.

Comment: Why are you uncoding to UTF-8 when your terminal or console doesn't take UTF-8? That's what is happening here: your terminal or console is decoding UTF-8 bytes as another codec.

Comment: I was printing without it. But then, it was giving UnicodeEncodeError.

Comment: @hash_ir: that's because your console or terminal can't handle a specific character in the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encoding Unicode text to UTF-8 before printing:

```
print key.encode('utf-8') + ' : ' + value.encode('utf-8')
```

Your console or terminal is not configured to interpret UTF-8 however. It is being sent bytes and it is then displaying characters based on a *different* codec altogether.

Your `value` contains a `\u2013` or [U+2013 EN DASH](https://codepoints.net/U+2013) character, which encodes to UTF-8 as 3 bytes `E2 80 93`, which your terminal appears to decode as Windows Codepage 437 instead:

```
>>> value = u'2005\u20132014'
>>> print value
2005–2014
>>> print value.encode('utf8').decode('cp437')
2005ΓÇô2014
```

Either re-configure your console or terminal, or set the [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) to use an error handler:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=cp437:replace
```

The `:replace` part will tell Python to encode to cp437 but to use *placeholders* for characters it can't handle. You'll get a question mark instead:

```
>>> print value.encode('cp437', 'replace')
2005?2014
```

Note that I have to encode to CP437 explicitly in all these examples. *You don't* as Python has detected your configuration and will do this automatically for you. Just stick to printing Unicode directly.

Another alternative is to use the [`Unicodecode` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) to replace non-ASCII characters with close approximations; it'll replace the en-dash with an ASCII dash:

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> value
u'2005\u20132014'
>>> unidecode(value)
'2005-2014'
```

Comment: Maybe point out also that the proper fix is to configure your system to handle UTF-8 output correctly.  Maybe link to one of the many duplicates of this FAQ.

Comment: If I directly print the key and value, following error is displayed:
**UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 11: character maps to <undefined>**

Comment: @tripleee: which on Windows is next to impossible, unfortunately.

Comment: How can I set the placeholder for such characters?

Comment: `unidecode` worked. Thanks for explaining all this. I'll keep it in mind next time.